# Is it possible in R to test for the existence of specified `grDevices::windowsFonts` and specify a backup if the test fails?

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts

I am working on a `ggplot2` extension package for my organization to use, to apply our design guidelines to all of our R charts. Part of this requires the use of specific fonts. We use the Whitney typeface on our published visualizations, but not all users have the required fonts installed on their computers. I would like the package to check whether Whitney is installed and, if not, specify an alternate, widely-available font (e.g. Calibri) to use as a backup.

The following code will run successfully, without warnings, regardless of whether "Whitney Medium" is actual installed on the PC. If it is not installed, the plotted text will display in Arial.

```
grDevices::windowsFonts(font_reg = "Whitney Medium")
graphics::plot(c(0,2), c(0,2), type="n", xlab="", ylab="")
graphics::par(family="font_reg")
graphics::text(1, 1, "font_reg", cex=4)
```

How can I verify that "Whitney Medium" is a valid font on a given PC, and specify a backup if it's not?

**Note:** Our Whitney font files are OTF, not TTF, so I can't use the `extrafont` package. I also would like to avoid using `showtext` because I really want to find a solution that works in the RStudio plotting window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `sysfonts::font_files()` to identify installed/available fonts, and using Calibri if Whitney is not in the results.

```
whitney_fonts <- dplyr::filter(sysfonts::font_files(),
  family == "Whitney Medium"
)
if (length(whitney_fonts$family) > 0) {
  grDevices::windowsFonts(font_reg = "Whitney Medium")
} else {
  grDevices::windowsFonts(font_reg = "Calibri")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for `windowsFonts` might need to be overwritten if you need to make this automatic. When called with no arguments, the available fonts are returned as a named list. Otherwise you might try something like as a preamble to your plotting call:

```
 if ("Whitney Medium" %in% names( windowsFonts()) ) {  .. proceed as usua } else {
                                                windowsFonts("sans" = "Arial") }
```

If you have `font_reg` as a text value passed to the graphics functions, then you might use that instead of "sans".